# resources not loading in spring mvc 4

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am creating a spring mvc project using gradle. But after build the resource folder is blank and so all js css files are not loading. I am not sure due to what setting this is happening.

webConfig :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.decorpot.spring.config", "com.decorpot.spring.controller", "com.decorpot.*" })
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver jspViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        bean.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
        .addResourceLocations("/resources/**")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/views/**").addResourceLocations("/views/**");
    }
}
```

web.xml :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.decorpot.spring.config</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Is there anything else i should look into.

Comment: For a Spring MVC 4 Gradle project that I worked with, Spring Boot expected me to put my static resources within a folder called 'static'. Within there I had my subfolders such as 'js', 'css', and 'images' which I was able to reference in my html templates such as filepath 'js/app.js'.

Comment: If you're using Spring Boot, you'll notice in the common application properties of the appendix [Common Properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties) the property `spring.resources.static-locations`. You may be able to set a specific location by creating an application.properties file and setting that value.